# Laravel 5.6: Get HDD serial number in a computer with windows and use it in a controller

Tags: php, windows, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to get the hdd serial number so I can use it in a controller.
I am using Windows 7. I can get the value in the console but I want to use it in a controller in my Laravel project.

Comment: whose hdd? client or the server? though i never think you can check using plain php.. trying [phpSysInfo](http://phpsysinfo.github.io/phpsysinfo/) for server side wont hurt.

Comment: You could try something like `shell_exec('vol C:')`

Comment: I forgot to mention it . My own HDD serial number.

Comment: I tried using `shell_exec('wmic diskdrive get serialnumber')`
But I get `invalid xml content` in a dd.